# Eigen in Visual C++ project. Very slow linking with Inline Function Expansion

Tags: visual-c++, linker, eigen

I am working on a simulation program heavy on matrix and vector algebra, for which I'm using Eigen, with Visual Studio (2017 and 2019, makes no difference) on a i7-3770k with 16Gb. I'm by no means an expert in C++ or Visual Studio.

Building in Debug mode, with all optimizations and Inline Function Expansion off is very fast, but execution time is massively slower than in release mode, to the point that testing and further work on the code is coming unmanageable. The problem is, compilation time in Release mode with certain optimizations is desperately slow. My program is quite small (around 23 source files, with anything between 50 and 1500 lines of code each).

I've traced back the key factor to be the Inline Function Expansion option. Depending on its setting, building and execution time for a certain simulation run look as follows:

```
/Ob0:          Build: 18s     Exec 42s  (disabled)
/Ob1 or /Ob2:  Build: 10m30s  Exec 0.9s   (only __inline, any suitable)
```

That is, activation of inline expansion makes the code x45 faster, but building time becomes x35 longer.

Is there any clear explanation of why linking becomes so slow when activating any of the Inline Function Expansion options? I guess Eigen is full of inlined functions, which makes obj file much bigger and slower to link, but the difference looks extreme to me.

And most important: is there any way to reduce the linking time with this option activated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it is linking time not compilation time? I can confirm that Eigen has a lot of functions which need to be inlined for descent performance. You may be able to split your code into smaller compilation units (make sure there are no "include everything" headers).

Comment: Could you post the code you use to include Eigen libraries? It is a bad idea doing `#include <Eigen>` if you can do something like `#include <Eigen/Core>` instead.

Comment: Thanks both of you for your replies.

@chtz. I'm quite sure the problem is the linking. If I select all the source files on the Solution Explorer and click on Compile or presse ctrl+F7, I see on the output window all the files being compiled and successfully finishing after 12s.

If I press shift+ctrl+B, I see the exact same output after about the same time, then "Generating code" and stays there until it finishes more than 10 minutes later.

Comment: If instead of that I click on "Project only -> Link only nameofmyproject" (which is the only way I know of for forcing linking without compiling) it goes directly to the "Generating code" message and takes again its +10 minutes to finish.

If I got it right, that all should mean it's the linking part what takes so long.

Comment: @Rockcat. At some point I substituted "#include <Eigen>" by "#include "eigen/eigen/dense" (for some reason "#include <Eigen/Dense> didn't work. It didn't make any dramatic difference.

I also have tried to use precompiled headers. Not sure whether it made a big difference in terms of compiling time, or whether I even did it right. All the figures I gave on my question were measured after I did this.

Comment: `#include <Eigen/Dense>` should work (and be preferred over `"eigen/eigen/dense"`) make sure that the folder containing the main `Eigen` directory is in your include path. And as @Rockcat suggested, try including only `<Eigen/Core>` at first.

Comment: `#include <Eigen/Dense>`  will include the files "Core", "LU",  "Cholesky", "QR", "SVD", "Geometry", "Eigenvalues". It is unlikely that you use all those modules. Anyway, those compilation times are crazy.

Comment: I suspect that you linking times are due to Interprocedural Optimization (IPO) active. Can you check `Optimization > Interprocedural Optimization`? Can you post your project file?

Comment: @Rockcat. I couldn't find that Interprocedural Optimization option. I've played around with the project settings and brought the build time down to around 3 minutes when the whole project has to be built again (after changing something in stdafx.h, for example), and to around 20 seconds when I only modify one file. Somehow the incremental? linking wasn't working before. But I would still like to share my project file... if you tell me how I can do it here. You may still be able to spot something wrong in it.

Comment: @chtz and Rockcat. I included the whole library because I'm testing different solvers from different packages. I tried to refine the package I actually included and it made a difference. But what actually brought the build time down to those 20 seconds after having only edited one file was something else.